# PHP Change end of value?

Tags: php, url, filenames

I am having some trouble with php.

I have a variable $image that contains a url, like

```
$image='http://example.com/image.jpg'
```

I am trying to change the name of the image to this, meanwhile **not changing the url:**

```
$image='http://example.com/image01.jpg'
$image='http://example.com/image02.jpg'
$image='http://example.com/image03.jpg'
and so on..
```

Any idea how I can do this?
Or should I use some Javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code:

```
$link = 'http://example.com/image.jpg';
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++) {
    $array[] = str_replace('.jpg',sprintf("%02d",$i).'.jpg',$link);
}
print_r($array);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://example.com/image01.jpg
    [1] => http://example.com/image02.jpg
    [2] => http://example.com/image03.jpg
)
```

**EDIT**

This works regardless of extension:

```
$link = 'http://example.com/image.png';
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++) {
    $array[] = substr_replace($link,sprintf("%02d",$i),strripos($link,'.'),0);
}
print_r($array);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://example.com/image01.png
    [1] => http://example.com/image02.png
    [2] => http://example.com/image03.png
)
```

Comment: Isn't supposed to be slower performing `substr_replace` and `strripos` each loop instead one for all then using plain string concatenation?

Comment: Benchmark doing 50.000 loops without `print_r` or `echo`: My code executes within 0.0676 seconds and your code within 0.0527 seconds. Caching is indeed faster, but the difference is not noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

This will add numbering before last `.` whichever is the `$image` file extension

```
$image = 'http://example.com/image.jpg';

$pos = strripos($image, '.');
$head = substr($image, 0, $pos);
$tail = substr($image, $pos);

for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++) {
    $image = $head.sprintf("%02d", $i).$tail;
}
```